# UIAccessibilityContainer dynamically update protocol methods

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, uiaccessibility

I have a custom UIView which I have implemented the informal protocol `UIAccessibilityContainer`.

My accessibility elements for this UIView differs depending on the state of the view. In my case it's a player, so when it's playing it has a stop button and when it's stopped it has a play button.

Therefore I dynamically need to update the `accessibilityElements` array when the state of my view changes.

When the view is initially setup it works as expected but when I need to update the `accessibilityElements` I don't know how to go about it, and if there's a method to tell "accessibility" that the elements have been updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, there is. You'll want to post a "Layout Changed" notification:

`UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification, elementToFocusOrNil);`